# How to enable my clients use a custom domain name

Tags: php, ip-address

I want people to be able to use a custom domain name to access an application I have hosted on my server. From what I have read, people can do this by changing the A Record of their accounts to my IP address. On this IP they are supposed to point to, I have other applications hosted there. How do I configure it on my own end such that when they set their A Name record and point it to my IP, I direct them to the folder where the application is.

I have a dedicated server running on Ubuntu Linux 9.10

Can any kind of script enable me to do this?